# Not able to access Rest Endpoint by machine name over vpn

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, vpn, resttemplate, netflix-eureka

I am facing issue with **Rest Endpoint**. When I am trying to access url with machine name instead of localhost, It is giving **Access Denied error**. It will give this error only over **VPN connection** otherwise it is working fine without VPN.

I do not have same issue with browser. Browser is able to identify url with machine name. This issue is only when I am trying to consume any **endpoint running on different microservice** on same machine through Java code or Postman

For Example, If I am consuming some endpoint in Java.

```
restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:8761/actuator/beans", Object.class).getBody()
//Working fine

restTemplate.getForEntity("http://my_machine_name:8761/actuator/beans", Object.class).getBody()
//Access denied
```

or through Postman

```
http://my_machine_name:8761/actuator/beans
```

Error: connect EACCES 192.xxx.x.x:8761

[image]

Mainly I am using **Discovery Client to identity the machine name and port** so that I need not to hard code **localhost** in the url. I am using **FeignClient for loadbalancer** but looks like **restTemplate** is also giving same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed above error. If you connect your machine with VPN, it change your network. So you need to find which ip address is getting used in your machine. Try ipconfig in command prompt to find the ip address in Windows.

If you give your machine name instead of above IP address then it will not be able to find your machine as your machine name is not available in your network (because of VPN connection).

```
machine.ip.address=XX.66.223.XXX
eureka.client.service-url.default-zone=http://${machine.ip.address}:8761/eureka
eureka.instance.hostname=${machine.ip.address}
```

Provide your network ip address in your URL instead of machine name to make it work.